# Jersey not honoring @Produces

Tags: jersey-2.0

I have this simple `@GET`:

```
@Path("/keepalive")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public Response keepalive() {
    return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).build();
}
```

When I call this on Firefox, this is what I get:

[image]

I explicitly defined `@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)`, so why is Jersey returning `application/json`?

Comment: Must be something you're _not_ showing us. It's showing the Content-Length as 7 while you're obviously not sending anything. And why does is say the server is Python? You sure you don't have another server running at that port?

Comment: Well, that might the issue, I am using SAM Local from Amazon AWS, to simulate an API Gateway call to Lambda. I am embedding a Jersey application inside a lambda. I am waiting for a reply from the Amazon team, but after some tests I am pretty sure SAM Local or the AWS Jersey Wrapper for Lambda is the culprit.